# How to interpret volatile when there are multiple levels of indirection

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, volatile, variable-declaration

Suppose I have the following

```
struct my_struct ** value;
```

I understand the difference between

```
struct my_struct volatile * other_value; // pointer is volatile
```

and

```
struct * volatile other_value; // what pointer points to is volatile
```

but what is the difference between

```
struct my_struct * volatile * value;  // call this (1)
```

and

```
struct my_struct ** volatile value;  // call this (2)
```

Is it correct to say that (1) means the pointer that is pointed to by value is volatile and (2) means value is volatile and the pointer it points to and the data that pointer points to is not volatile?  Or do I have it backwards?

More generally consider something that might look like this

```
struct my_struct ***** volatile *** value
```

which pointer in this "series" of pointers is the volatile pointer?  Would it be the pointer that is redirected (is this the correct terminology?) 3 times from value or 4?  Put another way, does volatile always operate on the right most value/ptr/statement (what would be the right terminology here?).

For example

```
struct my_struct ******** volatile value
```

means value is volatile

```
struct my_struct ******* volatile * value
```

means the pointer value points to is volatile

```
struct my_struct ****** volatile ** value
```

means the pointer pointed to by the pointer pointed to by value is volatile.  And so on.  Is my understanding correct?

Edit:
I was completely wrong.  volatile applies to the left not the right.

Comment: volatile is interpreted as const it applies to what is on the left and if it can't it applies to the right

Comment: Go here https://cdecl.org/ and paste in your defines.

Comment: @4386427 that is a nifty tool!.  Thanks.  I guess I was completely wrong lmao.

Comment: @4386427 Nah don't go there, that site fails more often than not. Try `int unsigned x` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that the *qualifier* (volatile or const etc) stick to what's on the left side of it.

> I understand the difference between
>
> `struct my_struct volatile * other_value; // pointer is volatile`
>
> and
>
> `struct * volatile other_value; // what pointer points to is volatile`
> ... Or do I have it backwards?

You have it backwards. The first case makes the struct data volatile, the second case makes the pointer itself volatile.

> `struct my_struct ***** volatile *** value`

This means that the left pointer `*  volatile` is volatile qualified.

In general, reading declarations in C from right-to-left helps:

- `other_value` other_value...
- `* other_value`  ...is a pointer...
- `struct my_struct volatile * other_value` ... to `struct my_struct volatile`.

Also please note that stupidly, C allows the qualifier in a variable declaration to be placed anywhere. Meaning that `volatile int* x;` and `int volatile* x;` are equivalent. There is no sound rationale for why this is allowed, it has just always been like that.

Comment: "Also please note that stupidly, C allows the qualifier in a variable declaration to be placed anywhere. Meaning that volatile int* x; and int volatile* x; are equivalent", yep that's what threw me off.  When you think about it always being to the left it makes perfect sense what is going on.